# can I recover the change of a TX?

Tags: transactions, change, revert-transaction

I was reading and I have a question, if you please can help me. I send 0.00335 BTC in this TX: bf3eedc1929042444e62badaf885a8dd49333c31ff40d023175a90da241ec2e0
and I see the 0.00335 as spent, but the change (that I didn't specify the address where to put it) went to another address, and it appears as unspent. What can I do to recover it? Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your wallet software will handle all of this for you. Your wallet software generated the change address and stored its private key. When you want to spend more Bitcoin, it will still know about the change and can spend from it. Your balance in your wallet should still include the change. There is nothing you have to do in order to spend the change, and there is no "recover" required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you was very clear! I hope to continue learning about Bitcoin and help to other in the future.